# Python Telegram bot where updates can be called manually inside larger script

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to integrate a telegram bot into my python script. The bot is not the primary part of the script, and i therefore need to call the chatupdates manually when it's time.

I have before used the method of requests, and this works fine for sending messages;

```
def SendNotification(message):
    TOKEN = <private stuff>
    chat_id = <again private stuff>
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TOKEN + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + message
    requests.get(url).json() # this sends the message
```

But i found it a bit inconsistant when calling for chatupdates (sometimes new messages wouldn't come up, and some chats would dissappear)

I've also used python-telegram.bot, which worked better and was more in the scope of what i wanted.

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes, Updater

TOKEN = <PRIVATE>
BOT_USERNAME = <PRIVATE>

async def StartCommand(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("Shits working")

async def HandleMessages(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    messageType = update.message.chat.type
    text = update.message.text
    
    print(f"User ({update.message.chat.id}) in {messageType}: '{text}'")
    
    await update.message.reply_text("Test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting")
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()
    
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, HandleMessages))

    print("polling")
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)
    print("after")
```

(^Most of this is from a youtube tutorial)

But the problem was that the methods i could find online was based on the bot being the sole purpose of the script (and multithreading might be a problem, as i use it in other parts of my script).

Answer (score 0):

While running a standalone chat bot is arguably the most important use case that `python-telegram-bot` is designed for, the "pure API wrapper" functionality is also available. Please have a look at [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API) which showcases this. TL;DR:

```py
async with Bot("TOKEN") as bot:
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=123, text="Hello World!")
```

Please also check out the [`python-telegram-bot-raw`](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot-raw/) library which provides *only* that functionality, without `telegram.ext`. You mal also be interested in [this wiki entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-requested-design-patterns#running-ptb-alongside-other-asyncio-frameworks) about how running a chatbout alongside other functionality works.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.